# Send JSON file in response to a request, Flask

Tags: python, json, flask, request, response

I have an endpoint which is receiving a text file from a request, which the flask server processes and now need to send a response which should be a json file. I have read and performed the operations of received txt file, and now when I send the dict by jsonify I get this in terminal.

> Response 444 bytes [200 OK]

How do I get the json file or is there any other way of sending the JSON file in response? Since I won't be in control of the server that will send the request I need a way to send JSON file.

Code Handling the response

```
@app.route('/automated_testing', methods=['GET','POST'])
def getfile():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        for file in request.files:
            links = request.files[file].read()
            #Since a byte sized object is returned
            links = [links.decode('utf8').strip()]
            links = links[0].split("\n")

        res = dict()
        for i in links:
            f = FlarePredictor(i)
            res[i] = f[0]

        print(jsonify(res), file=sys.stderr)
        return jsonify(res)
    else:
        return "GET REQ"

    return "Hi"
```

Code used to send the request

```
import requests

with open('test.txt', 'rb') as f:
    r = requests.post('http://127.0.0.1:5000/automated_testing', files={'test.txt': f})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`requests` supports JSON out-of-the-box](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/master/user/quickstart/#json-response-content):

```
json = r.json()
```

Now `json` will be a regular Python dictionary containing the data.

Comment: Now, it gives JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0). I have printed the dict that is jsonified it is not empty.

Comment: @YatinGupta, what's `r.content` that you receive?

Comment: @YatinGupta, and that's the cause of the problem! BTW, according to the code you posted, the line `return "Hi"` will never be reached. Please post the actual code you're running

Comment: r.json() works !. Sorry I had commented on the return to debug, forgot to uncomment. Thanks !